# Using ASP.NET MVC 6 Web API Identity when I have a token from FB

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using FB SDK for iOS to login my users. My understanding is that I can get a granted token from SDK on the client side and use it to authenticate users in my Web API. What I can't understand is how to use `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` to authenticate my users only with a token.

Answer (score 0):

You need JWT Bearer authentication.

Facebook grants you an `access_token` in JSON Web Token (JWT) format. Include that as a bearer token in your Web API requests.

```
GET http://www.webapi.com/v1/people
Authorization: Bearer the_facebook_access_token_goes_here
```

Then use the ASP.NET Security JWT bearer middleware. It will read the token and populate the `HttpContext.User.Identity`.

The ASP.NET team has a sample here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/samples/JwtBearerSample Here are the fundamentals of how to configure JWT Bearer authentication.

project.json

```
dependencies : {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0-*",
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication();
}

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    // set these to the Facebook Authority and Audience
    Authority = "" 
    Audience = ""
});
```

Decorate your Web API actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

That might be enough to get you started.